Is it possible to dismiss the PIP player, but keep playing the video's audio in the YouTube app?
Every once in a while, for no discernible difference in my actions, I will have started playing a video on YouTube and then return to the Home Screen or a different app, and the PIP player never loads. The video's audio continues playing and the app context is present in the Dynamic Island (the YouTube icon and animated waveform representation are present). If I pop back to YouTube, and then leave it again, the PIP player always loads from what I remember.
This is obviously some sort of small-time bug, but why does it happen? Is it possible to "dismiss" the PIP player, more than just sliding it into the edge of the screen? Can I specifically control the dismissal and re-invocation of the PIP player?
I know that I can make it almost as wide as the screen, or about 1/3rd of the width by double tapping the player, as well as positioning it into the corners via swiping, and pushing it over the edge so there is only a tab allowing me to recall it; But can I dismiss the player's visual presence entirely but continue playback consistently?

There is a consistent way to get playback without the PIP player: Pause the video in YouTube, exit YouTube, press play via the Control Center, or any other external media control means. The PIP player never pops up.
I believe the reason why this bug happens in the first place is because modern streaming uses two streams; a separately connected to, but played in sync video stream and the audio stream. For whatever reason even though the video is playing, the video stream isn't "registered" in a way that it pops the PIP player when backgrounded, when done quickly enough. This is probably as simple as a race condition. I don't expect that the YouTube iOS app has an in-app way to disable PIP but maintain playback.
